# What is the best way to ensure the last row is the only row deleted from a dataset

Tags: r

I have wrote the code...

```
data[-nrow(data),]
```

to remove the last row of my dataset. However, if you run this line multiple times it continues to delete the last row. Just curious is there a better way of writing this to ensure that only 1 last row is deleted or this line can only be run once?

Comment: use the actual rownumber you want deleted?

Comment: Save the last row before running for the first time, `n <- nrow(data)`. Then something like `data[-n, ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @RAB.

For mtcars

```
nrow(mtcars)
```

This gives 32, so the next line of code would be

```
mtcars[1:31 ,]
```

If you don't want to manually change the code based on the results of nrow, you can also do this

```
df1 <- mtcars
df2 <- df1[1:(nrow(df1)-1), ]
```